# Counting elements

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

How many odd integers from 1000 through 9999 have
distinct digits?

So the answer in the book is what I expected, but I can't figure out why it is 8 X 8 x 7 x 5?
Why isn't the first digit 9? Since the first digit be zero (10 - 1) = 1 to 9 options.

Comment: @TaisukeYasuda Yeah I agree with that but wouldn't it be 9 instead of 8

Comment: Out of the 10 digits, one of them is $0$, and one of them is used as the odd units digit.

Comment: Oh, careless mistake, my apologies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say there are 3 cases, that the tens digit is a zero, the hundreds digit is a zero, and all 4 digits are non-zero.

For each of the first two cases, the number of possible integers is

$$8 \times 7 \times 1 \times 5$$

For the third case, the number of possible integers is

$$8 \times 7 \times 6 \times 5$$

Twice the first number plus the second number gives

$$8 \times 7 \times 8 \times 5$$

---

Merging the three cases, as suggested by @stewbasic:

Consider the unit digit, there are $5$ possible digits from the odd condition.

Consider the thousands digit, there are $8$ possible digits, which is one fewer for the zero and one fewer for the odd unit digit than $10$.

For the remaining hundreds and tens digit, there are no restrictions and there are $8\times 7$ possible digit pairs.

So the answer is $8 \times 8 \times 7 \times 5$.

Comment: I guess if you choose the 4th digit, then 1st, then 2nd, then 3rd, you can avoid splitting into cases.

Comment: @peterwhy how did you get the first case?

Comment: @user1238097 For the first case, there is one possible tens digit (0), $5$ possible units digit, $8$ possible thousands digit, $7$ possible hundreds digit.

Comment: @peterwhy shoot I didn't even think about the last digit having a effect on the number of first digits.  The 8 the is the one hundred place is the number after choosing the last digit and first than correct since one odd number and (odd/even number) have already been chosen

Comment: The last digit won't have *any* effect on the first digits.  But the first digits will all have an effect on the last.  That is why you should do the last digit first.  Then the first digit has no effect on the second and third but the second and third will have effects on the first.  So you should do the first digit second.  The remaining two digits can be done in either order.

Answer (score 5):

Let the number be ABCD.  There are 5 choices that D could be; 1,3,5,7, or 9.  Once D is chosen there are 8 choices A could be; anything other than 0 or D.  Then there are 8 options B could be; anything but D or A.  And there are 7 choices C can be; anything but A, B or D.

Yes, if you choose A *before* you choose D there are 9 choices but then you have to make cases when choosing D based upon whether A was odd or even.  It can be done but it's tedious and complicated.

Comment: @fleabood Is it always better to move from right to left

Comment: No.  It must certainly certainly is not **always** better.  All things being equal it might be better for the sake of keeping track, but if some terms have special conditions those conditions will influence how you set up the problem.  In this case, as D is must be odd and the doing A,B, or C first will effect the options of D, you must *certainly* should do D first, A second, as B or C being 0 affect A, and B or C last.

Comment: Stewbasic's answer also explains if you do A first there are 9 choices of A but you must separate the 5 of them which are odd, from the 4 of them which are even.  Then there are 9 choices for B.  But you must separate the 20 where A and B are both odd, the 12 where they are both even and the 40 where one is even.  Then there are 7 choices for C but you must separate the 60 where all three are odd, the twenty two where all are even the 80 where C and one other are odd and 60 where C is even and one other is odd.  Then either have 2,3,4 or 5 choices for D depending on how many ods and evens ....

Answer (score 1):

peterwhy explains how to get the correct answer. Here's why (my guess at) your intended strategy doesn't work.

We try to go from left to right, multiplying the number of possible digits. As you note, the first digit has $9$ options as it is nonzero. The second must be different from the first, leaving $9$ options. Similarly the third has $8$ options. Hence there are $9\times 9\times 8$ options for the first 3 digits.

However we have a problem for the last digit: the number of possibilities depends on how many odd numbers we already used. eg there are 5 ways to complete $246*$ but only 2 ways to complete $135*$. We'd need this number $c$ to be independent of the preceding choices to get $9\times9\times8\times c$ for the final count.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go left to right:

Let ABCD be the number.

There are 5 ways A can be odd and 4 ways A can be even so there are 5+4=9 ways to chose A.

There are $5*4$ ways A and B are both odd, $5*4$ ways A is odd B even, and $4*5$ A is even and B is odd and $4*3$ ways A and B can both be even.  So there are $5*4+(5*4+5*4)+4*3=9*8$ ways to choose A and B.

There are $5*4*3$ ways so that A,B,C are all odd.  There are $5*4*4$ ways for A and B to be odd and C even.There are $(5*4+4*5)*4$ that One of A or B is odd and C is odd.  There are $(5*4+4*5)*3$ ways for one of A or B to be odd and C even. There are $4*3*5$ ways for only C to be even. There are $4*3*2$ ways for A,B,C to be even.  So the are $5*4*3 + [(5*4+4*5)*4+5*4*4]+[(5*4+4*5)*3+4*3*5]+4*3*2=9*8*7$ ways to chose A,B, and C.

Now D must be odd. If A,B,C are all odd there are $5*4*3*2$ ways to do it.  If 2 of A,B, or C are odd there are $[(5*4+4*5)*4+5*4*4]*3$ ways to do it.  If one of A,B,C there are $[(5*4+4*5)*3+4*3*5]*4$ ways to do it.  If A,B,C are all even, there are $4*3*2*5$ ways to do this.

So in total there are $5*4*3*2+[(5*4+4*5)*4+5*4*4]*3+[(5*4+4*5)*3+4*3*5]*4+4*3*2*5=8*8*7*5\ne 9*8*7*5$ ways to do this.

I hope you see why it is better to figure the ways to do D odd first.  Then for A,B,C we it will not make any difference if they are odd or even.  In which case the answer is $5*8*8*7$.